# Closed form for CDF of Beta distribution on $[a,b]$?

Tags: probability-distributions

I am trying to derive the CDF of a Beta distribution defined on the interval $[a,b]$. I managed to get the PDF for this more general version of Beta, with the following result:
$$ f(\alpha, \beta, x) = \frac{(x-a)^{\alpha-1} (b-x)^{\beta-1}}{B(\alpha, \beta) (b-a)^{\alpha+\beta+1}} $$
Now, I was trying to get the CDF from that, by calculating the integral, but whatever I was getting, was likely incorrect as it wouldn't have the properties of the CDF such that $F(a) = 0$, $F(b) = 1$. Is there an easier way to approach that, i.e. perhaps doing a transformation of the CDF of the standard Beta distribution?

Comment: If $X$ is Beta on $[a,b]$ then $X=a+(b-a)X_0$ where $X_0$ is Beta on $[0,1]$. In terms of CDF, this reads $$F(x)=P(X\leqslant x)=P(X_0\leqslant(x-a)/(b-a))=F_0((x-a)/(b-a))$$

Comment: If $\alpha$ **and** $\beta$ are integers $\geq 1$, $F$ is clearly a polynomial on $[a,b]$, otherwise $F$ is, at best, expressible with transcendental functions (elliptic functions, etc...).

Comment: Incomplete Beta function, in particular.  @JeanMarie is right, it is transcendental.

Comment: @kimchi lover You are right : I was forgetting that this cdf has this name (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html).

Comment: @Did, thank you, this is what I was looking for but was not sure I can do that.